# firefox --help Nothing to see on Stdout

Tags: command-line, firefox, stdout

When running `firefox --help` or `firefox -h` there's nothing to see in the command window.

When running `firefox --help | more`, the help text is visible:

```
Usage: firefox [ options ... ] [URL]
       where options include:

  -h or --help       Print this message.
  -v or --version    Print Firefox version.
  -P <profile>       Start with <profile>.
  --profile <path>   Start with profile at <path>.
  --migration        Start with migration wizard.
  --ProfileManager   Start with ProfileManager.
  --no-remote        Do not accept or send remote commands; implies
                     --new-instance.
  --new-instance     Open new instance, not a new window in running instance.
  --UILocale <locale> Start with <locale> resources as UI Locale.
  --safe-mode        Disables extensions and themes for this session.
  --allow-downgrade  Allows downgrading a profile.
  --MOZ_LOG=<modules> Treated as MOZ_LOG=<modules> environment variable,
                     overrides it.
  --MOZ_LOG_FILE=<file> Treated as MOZ_LOG_FILE=<file> environment variable,
                     overrides it. If MOZ_LOG_FILE is not specified as an
                     argument or as an environment variable, logging will be
                     written to stdout.
  --console          Start Firefox with a debugging console.
  --headless         Run without a GUI.
  --save-recordings  Save recordings for all content processes to a directory.
  --browser          Open a browser window.
  --new-window <url> Open <url> in a new window.
  --new-tab <url>    Open <url> in a new tab.
  --private-window <url> Open <url> in a new private window.
  --preferences      Open Options dialog.
  --screenshot [<path>] Save screenshot to <path> or in working directory.
  --window-size width[,height] Width and optionally height of screenshot.
  --search <term>    Search <term> with your default search engine.
  --setDefaultBrowser Set this app as the default browser.
  --first-startup    Run post-install actions before opening a new window.
  --kiosk Start the browser in kiosk mode.
  --jsconsole        Open the Browser Console.
  --jsdebugger [<path>] Open the Browser Toolbox. Defaults to the local build
                     but can be overridden by a firefox path.
  --wait-for-jsdebugger Spin event loop until JS debugger connects.
                     Enables debugging (some) application startup code paths.
                     Only has an effect when `--jsdebugger` is also supplied.
  --devtools         Open DevTools on initial load.
  --start-debugger-server [ws:][ <port> | <path> ] Start the debugger server on
                     a TCP port or Unix domain socket path. Defaults to TCP port
                     6000. Use WebSocket protocol if ws: prefix is specified.
  --recording <file> Record drawing for a given URL.
  --recording-output <file> Specify destination file for a drawing recording.
  --remote-debugger [<host>][:<port>]
  --remote-debugging-port <port> Start the Firefox remote agent, which is
                     a low-level debugging interface based on the CDP protocol.
                     Defaults to listen on localhost:9222.
```

`firefox --help > help.txt` writes the helptext in the file.

Is this the normal behavior for `--help` option and why?

Comment: Question probably needs more information, I cannot reproduce (`firefox --full-version Mozilla Firefox 78.0.2 20200709200106 20200709200106`)

Comment: Weird, I can confirm that for me on `Mozilla Firefox 78.0.2 20200708170202 20200708170202` `--help` indeed does not print to `stdout`, but does pipe to a file or other command. Same for `--full-version`. Makes no difference whether Firefox is running at the time or not. Firefox claims it is up to date. Are you on a nightly, @einfeyn496?

Comment: I can reproduce this too. Win10, Firefox 76.0.1. I noticed that the cursor momentarily shows the loading icon, but nothing prints to cmd.

Comment: Curious... maybe a Windows/linux difference? I'm on the standard repo version for arch (`78.0.2-1`), i.e., not running anything exotic (also tested on both `zsh` and `bash`)

Comment: Tested on a Fedora 32 box as well with ` firefox --full-version Mozilla Firefox 78.0.2 20200709140757 20200709140757` and still have the full `--help` dumped to the terminal.  If I do `firefox --help 1>/tmp/stdout.txt 2>/tmp/stderr.txt`, only `/tmp/stdout.txt` has any content.